# Insert link to internal page in accordion title

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, accordion

I would like all functions of the attached code to to remain as is however I would like for the titles of each accordion to be a link to another page while opening the accordion dropdown. Everytime I try all I get is either the accordion w/out a successful link or the other way around.

If you need anymore info please let me know.

**TLDR: attach a href to the label "label one"**

I am currently working with the code attached to trouble shoot my problem
https://jsfiddle.net/11wunqqz/4/

```css
/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.blue label {
  background: #2980b9;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

.blue .tab-content {
  background: #3498db;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 1em;
}


/* :checked */

input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 10em;
}


/* Icon */

label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label::after {
  content: "+";
}

input[type=radio]+label::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-four" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-five" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-five">Label Two</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-six" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-six">Label Three</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand you right you may simply insert a link to your `<label>` tags:

`<label for="tab-five"><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Label</a></label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TLDR: attach a href to the label "label one"

EDIT:
I have seen your comment:

> inserting the href overruns the accordion function

You didn't specify if you want to avoid JavaScript, but my solution involves it.
My solution is to ADD a click event to your label.
Look at my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/j5L8rhtm/

I run a JavaScript code after the page completes to load and parse (this is very important, since I require to access the DOM), which consists into adding a `click` event to all the `label` tags which have a `data-href` attribute.

It kinda acts like `a href`, but it uses JavaScript to **add** an event and avoid overriding the events already bound to that item. Infact, I have used the `addEventListener` method to add an anonymous function to the `click` event.

Then I use the `window.open` function to open a new window. You can also open a new tab. [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for the arguments.

Some people might say that `window.open` should be avoided, but if you use it to open ONE window/tab in a `click` event is kinda fine to use it, because it's a user-triggered action. It's "resistant" to browser's popup restrictions and "harder" popup blocker extensions (I have one of those and my fiddle code still works fine).

I don't know if you have any JavaScript skills, but with my code in that fiddle you can just write and assign the `data-href` attribute on your `label` tags.

---

ORIGINAL:

I have just edited:

```
<label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
```

To:

```
<label for="tab-four"><a href="https://www.google.com">Label One</a></label>
```

It just works. I wrapped the "Label One" into a `a` tag with the `href` attribute. You can put any value in it, like an anchor (to jump to a specific part of your page without refreshing). You can also specify a `target` attribute. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) for more informations.

Comment: Unfortunately inserting the href overruns the accordion function of the tab and the text works as a link but doesn't create the drop down.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a working fiddle. Check it out!

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Unfortunately I'm not so fluent in coding... I'm trying to make my website and maybe thats a terrible move but I'm almost there so if you're willing to keep helping me with this one prob I'd really appreciate it!

What I'm trying to do is make a navigation bar on the left side of the page that is always there and when you click on the title of the accordion, it would open the page while opening a description below (the hidden portion). I'm using cargo.site to build the website so the page is already cut in two (navigation on left and separate pages on right).

Comment: Here's another example that kind of works.https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate

I just need the accordions to collapse once another is clicked

Comment: First of all, it seems that I have answered your question quite correctly. Now you are asking a completely different question. You should accept my answer first, if it's correct. That's how StackOverflow works!